# No HandlerMappings found in servlet 'DispatcherServlet': using default

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I am trying to webapp basic project using Spring MVC (starter project STS 3.7.0). Java 1.7 
WebConfig.java

```
package com.terafast;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.terafast")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return resolver;
    }
}
```

WebAppInitializer.java

```
package com.terafast;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("*.html");
    }

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new  AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation("com.terafast.WebConfig");

        return context;
    }

}
```

HomeController

```
package com.terafast.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/index")
    public String index(Model model) {

        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

I created welcome.jsp in webapp/WEB-INF/view/ path. When I run project as server I got nothing on http://localhost:8080/TEM/ . I also got nothing when I use http://localhost:8080/TEM/index.html .

```
18:18:29.911 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] WARN o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TEM/index] in DispatcherServlet with name 'DispatcherServlet' 
18:18:29.911 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

[image]
Could someone explain what is the problem?

Comment: The `/` will never match your mapping for the `DispatcherServlet` and `/index` will not match `/index.html`. Map your `DispatcherServlet` to `/` instead of `*.html`.

Comment: I change it to addMapping("/") and tried  /index url. but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Also your `prefix` should start with a `/` so `/WEB-INF` instead of `WEB-INF`. Enable DEBUG logging or `org.springframework.web` to see why it it fails, does it really fail on the url requested or on view rendering.

Comment: not works! still the same problem.

Comment: please enable debug logging and post the output...

Comment: 18:18:29.911 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/project/index] in DispatcherServlet with name 'DispatcherServlet'
18:18:29.911 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request

Comment: Please don't add logging as comments add it as an improvement to your question!!! Also the URL doesn't match what you have here so indeed nothing will be found... `/home` != `/index`.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I updated my question.

Comment: Judging from your comment and the logging I highly doubt you are actually calling the correct URL. You are modifying and thus obfuscating things...

Comment: I'm also wondering is your project deployed at `/project` or simply the root `/`...

Comment: thats because I'm trying to fix the project now. but the main question is exactly what I asked. project/index

Comment: Don't change things as that generally makes it harder to point to the issues. But as mentioned I highly doubt you are calling the correct URL at all and/or that your application is actually deployed at `/project`

Comment: I add screenshot and change "project" to "TEM". that is exactly what I have now

Comment: That still doesn't make any difference... You can give it any name it doesn't mean it is deployed as that. As stated enable debug and see what happens, during startup (to see if it gets registered) and request processing (to see what is handled)

Answer (score 1):

Hey i faced the same problem what you can do is go to your project properties >> DeploymentAssembly and then add your DispatcherServlet library wherever it is.

This will resolve your issue.

Comment: can you explain that step by step?

Comment: I am explaining the steps required when you are using eclipse IDE. 1. Go to your project properties. 2. In the left side of your project properties you will see Deployment Assembly 3. In Deployment Assembly there is add button on the right side. 4. If you are keeping your DispatcherServlet in WEB-INF/lib add that folder there.

Comment: Where exactly have you placed your Spring-Core jar? Can you share screenshot if possible for Spring Core place and your DeploymentAssembly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83982/discussion-between-pka-and-kulbhushan-singh).